# Can't run gradle wrapper with docker build

Tags: java, docker, gradle

I have this small build:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk as build-java
COPY java-project /root/project
WORKDIR /root/project
RUN chmod +x ./gradlew
RUN ls
RUN ./gradlew ...
```

```
#9 [build-build-java 5/6] RUN ls
#9 sha256:2d05b1e31ea4eaa8a9343b4f48fadcf7351b9d55dcc9c27e572d7bb32c4d723c
#9 0.194 build
#9 0.194 build.gradle
#9 0.194 docker-compose.yml
#9 0.194 gradle
#9 0.194 gradlew
#9 0.194 gradlew.bat
#9 0.194 HELP.md
#9 0.194 lombok.config
#9 0.194 settings.gradle
#9 0.194 src
#9 DONE 0.2s

#10 [build-build-java 6/6] RUN ./gradlew ...
#10 sha256:62cb4a1a6288008f3faccc3504e63ef87d30c3d7fde904a0576ffcf571e9b310
#10 0.310 /bin/sh: 1: ./gradlew: not found
#10 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ./gradlew ...]: exit code: 127
```

I've bene stuck on this for a while now.

I've tried using `FROM gradle` instead and then using `gradle ...` but then I get this file mount error:

```
#10 sha256:26de7798a76971c3eb12e6398f830ee487fe41c110d0f8ca6a23a92ee5437267
#10 0.854 
#10 0.854 Welcome to Gradle 7.3.3!
#10 0.854
#10 0.854 Here are the highlights of this release:
#10 0.854  - Easily declare new test suites in Java projects
#10 0.855  - Support for Java 17
#10 0.855  - Support for Scala 3
#10 0.855
#10 0.855 For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/release-notes.html
#10 0.855
#10 0.952 Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
#10 2.153 Unable to list file systems to check whether they can be watched. Assuming all file systems can be watched. Re
ason: Could not query file systems: could not open mount file (errno 2: No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Are you by chance building the image from Windows?

Comment: @thokuest I am. i was wondering if this is some bug with WSL or something?

Comment: The Gradle wrapper `gradlew` is a shell script, and if shell scripts get copied in with DOS line endings, you could get a "not found" error like this.

Comment: I saw someone make this comment and I switched the line endings to "LF" from "CLRF" in intellij, but it didn't fix it @DavidMaze

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem with the Windows environment. This happens according to carriage return (`\r`) line endings in the bash script as [@thokuest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5006866/thokuest) pointed out. But you should consider when you changed the line ending to `LF` from `CLRF` in IntelliJ, the `gradlew` file in the container is not changed accordingly and it is cached from your previous `docker build .` command. So you should run this command:

`docker build --no-cache .`

or:

`docker build --no-cache --progress=plain .` if you want to see full output.

Comment: thanks a lot! forgot about "--no-cache"

Answer (score 2):

`/bin/sh: 1: ./gradlew: not found` is usually caused by carriage return (`\r`) line endings in the bash script. Removing the carriage return will most like resolve the issue.

Comment: I saw someone make this comment and I switched the line endings to "LF" from "CLRF" in intellij, but it didn't fix it

Answer (score 2):

Got exact same problem on Windows environment. This has to do with the line endings of the shell script files.

I fixed it this way:

1. Step - set the line endings to match the *nix style

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

2. Delete the git repo and re-clone it using the updated configuration
3. Relaunch the docker build

**NB!** just setting the configuration without re-cloning the repo doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run dos2unix command like below

```
dos2unix ./gradlew
```

And then don't forget to run the docker build with --no-cache, to avoid picking layer caches from your previous `docker build`  like below

```
 docker build --no-cache .
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting EOL to UNIX (LF) of the gradlew file should work.
It can be fixed using notepad++.

- Open the gradlew file in notepad++
- Edit -> EOL Conversion -> UNIX (LF)
- save