# docker-compose cannot find file even though ls can see it

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to execute a command inside a docker-compose file

```
services:
  jar-build:
    image: myImage
    working_dir: /opt/build
    volumes:
      - "../:/opt/build/"
    command: "./gradlew build"
```

running `docker-compose -f aboveFile.yaml run jar-build`  returns

> exec ./gradlew: no such file or directory

however if I change the command to be a simple `ls`

```
services:
  jar-build:
    image: myImage
    working_dir: /opt/build
    volumes:
      - "../:/opt/build/"
    command: "ls"
```

I get

```
Dockerfile
build.gradle
docker
gradle
gradle.properties
gradlew
gradlew.bat
jfrog.gradle
lombok.config
settings.gradle
src
```

Why can it not find the gradlew file even though `ls` shows it as there?
A `whoami` commands shows I am `root`

gradlew is a shell script
I am using docker for windows with git bash and it is a linux container

edit: the first line of the gradlew file is `#!/bin/sh`
running the command `echo $SHELL` returns (I did not copy incorrectly)

> C:Program FilesGitusrbinbash.exe

edit2: gradlew and the build.yaml are LF endings

edit3: I'm not entirely sure what I did here.  I re-cloned our repository a few times which may have cleared some cache somewhere.  I also ran `git config --global core.autocrlf input` and restarted but the mysterious error is gone and now I'm left with  `Could not connect to the Gradle daemon.` which sucks for me, but isn't the target for this question.

Comment: What is the "shebang" line of the script?  What is in `myImage`?  You mention a Windows host; is it possible the file is checked out on the host with DOS line endings?  (Do you need this as a "service" that will be re-run every time you `docker-compose up`, or should this be a `RUN` line in a Dockerfile?)

Comment: 0. Shebang is `version: "3.3"` but I'm having difficulties even running this as a `docker run` command that I'm looking into
1. This is used as part of my companies build process.  myImage only contains a java sdk.
2. I need to investigate this
3. Yes, it should build every time

Comment: David was asking about the shebang line of the `gradlew` script (if that is in fact a script and not a compiled binary).

Comment: This is also a common error if `gradlew` is symlinked into the host, such that the container cannot resolve that link.

Comment: gradlew is a physical file.  The top line of it shouldn't matter because the bash can't even recognize it as a file `exec ./gradlew: no such file or directory`

Comment: The first line of it is critical.  If it has DOS line endings `#!/bin/sh\r` then you'll get that error; you'll also get that error if the shebang line explicitly calls for `bash` but the underlying image doesn't contain that (for example, it's an Alpine-based image).

Comment: (I might expect you to run `gradle build` in a Dockerfile, without volumes, and not declared as a long-running Compose process, but you'd be likely to hit a similar issue; for example [Can't run gradle wrapper with docker build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70844518/cant-run-gradle-wrapper-with-docker-build).)

Comment: What do get if you change `command` to `echo $0`? In order to know which shell actually gets executed? E.g. `zsh` rather wants `. ./gradlew build`.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a feeling looking over it, but docker compose is trying to execute the gradle build command within the docker container (where it is not located), not from your system.

```
command overrides the default command declared by the container image (i.e. by Dockerfile’s CMD).
```

> CMD
>
> The CMD instruction has three forms:
>
> ```
> CMD ["executable","param1","param2"] (exec form, this is the preferred form)
> CMD ["param1","param2"] (as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)
> CMD command param1 param2 (shell form)
> ```
>
> There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list
> more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect.

And I guess as gradle is a build tool it should be specified within the dockerfile.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues when running stuff with `./hello-world` in the terminal. Try changing the command to `sh ./gradlew build`.

```
command: 'sh ./gradlew build'
```